# How to pass initial values into Material-UI multiple Select with chips using redux-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I'm trying to create multiple select control with redux-form and material ui. Actually, i use `redux-form-material-ui` wrapper, just couldn't add it as a tag.
Here is a part of my code:

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
              <InputLabel>Shops</InputLabel>
              <Field
                name="shops" component={Select} fullWidth
                multiple format={(value) => (Array.isArray(value) ? value : [])}
                renderValue={(selected) => (
                  <div className={classes.chips}>
                    {selected.map((value) => <Chip key={value.id} label={value.name} className={classes.chip} />)}
                  </div>
                )}
              >
                {allShops.map((shop) => <MenuItem key={shop.id} value={shop}>{shop.name}</MenuItem>)}
              </Field>
        </FormControl>
```

where `Select` is an `redux-form-material-ui` `Select`, `allShops` is an array passed from external component as a prop.
Everithyng seems to be fine when this stuff renderes - i have correctly rendered `Chip`s corresponding to my `initialValues`, but for some reason Menu (or DropdownList or whatever renders MenuItems) remains untouched by these values. If i try to select some items and deselect them - chips are keeping added and removed, menu items are becoming "selected" and "deselected", but this happenes only with "new" shops. How can i make this work correct way? I need not only chips being correctly rendered depending on initialValues, but also these MenuItems, so I could, for example, deselect selected values after form rendering. Can anyone help me? Would appreciate that.

Comment: I see that you are formatting the values. The format picks up just the values. If you reformat or remove the formatting, you would likely get the desired output